# Processing time for UK standard visa in the USA

Tags: visas, uk

I am a resident of the United States, and I want to apply for a UK standard visa. I thought I had plenty of time, because the processing time is stated to be three weeks. It turns out that you can't just go to a consulate-general to submit an application. They want you to fill out an application online, go to a Homeland Security application support center, and then send them the documents by mail. Of course, the next available appointment at a Homeland Security application support center is two weeks away.

Does anyone know if it's three weeks from the day you submit the application online, or three weeks from the day they get the documents in the mail?

Comment: Tried asking them?

Comment: It’s more likely to be 3 weeks from the day they get your documents, since without those the appplication isn’t complete

Answer (score 2):

The clock starts when the entire application package arrives at the UKVI processing center. Its [Visa Processing Times tool](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/united-states/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less) indicate that most applications from the US are processed within 15 working days, not counting weekends and public holidays, with a large majority, 75%, taking 10 business days.

> **Visits Visas: General Visit** (6 months or less)
>
> Number of days to process application ➣  % of applications decided
>
> - 3 days   ➣ 2%
> - 5 days   ➣ 9%
> - 10 days  ➣ 75%
> - 15 days  ➣ 97%
> - 30 days  ➣ 99%
> - 60 days  ➣  100%